# premature output after switch-case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

amateur question....my code has a menu of logic gates for the user to choose 3 gates from. The program then looks to a namespace in a header file and returns the output of that gate, which i stored in out[]. The gate outputs are working fine but I can't seem to print them AFTER 3 choices of switch-case has ended. I tried putting it into its own function "void output()" but still the program prematurely prints the outputs before the user can select 2 more gates.

outs y 1 to 3 should be printed together but the first one prints immediately after user enters logic inputs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "lab3.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace Gates;
void output( int o[]);


int menu(int, int);
int main()
{

    int a;
    cout << "Types of gates available:\n"
         << "1) AND\n"
         << "2) OR\n"
         << "3) NAND\n"
         << "4) NOR\n"
         << "5) XOR\n";


    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
    cout << "\nSelect gate #" << i+1 << " (1 to 5) => ";
    cin >> a;
    menu(a, i);
    }
}



int menu(int x, int j)
{

int out[3];
int a, b;
switch(x)
{
case 1:
    cout << "Enter two inputs for gate #" << j+1 << " (seperated by a space)      => ";
    cin >> a >> b;  // two inputs for gate
    out[j] = Gates::AND(a, b);   //store gate output in out1  (1 or 0)  
    break;

case 2:
    cout << "Enter two inputs for gate #" << j+1 << " (seperated by a space) => ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    out[j] = Gates::OR(a, b);   
    break;  

case 3:
    cout << "Enter two inputs for gate #" << j+1 << " (seperated by a space) => ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    out[j] = Gates::NAND(a, b);
    break;

case 4:
    cout << "Enter two inputs for gate #" << j+1 << " (seperated by a space) => ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    out[j] = Gates::NOR(a, b);
    break;

case 5:
    cout << "Enter two inputs for gate #" << j+1 << " (seperated by a space) => ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    out[j] = Gates::XOR(a, b);
    break;  
}

output(out);

return 0;
}

void output( int o[])
{
    cout << "\nOutputs => " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(10) << "\ny"<< i+1 << " = " << o[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input/ouput?

Comment: i just want to know proper syntax for displaying output based on more than one switch-case choice

Comment: @steeele _"based on more than one switch-case choice"_ You need to put the switch case in running in a loop, if more than one value should be chosen, or did I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be because you are calling `output` from within the  `menu`function, whereas you probably intended it to be called from the `main` function, probably after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Store the input from user and call the menu function after user inputs,

```
int a[3];
int out[3];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
cout << "\nSelect gate #" << i+1 << " (1 to 5) => ";
cin >> a[i];
menu(a[i],out i);
}
output(out);
```

I would strongly recommend you to study your own code flow either using a debugger or placing printf's in your code for beginning.

Comment: when you wrote  menu(a[i], out i)  did you mean  out[i] ??

Comment: in your code you used out as local variable in menu function and called output function from menu, so it will work, but if you want to call output from main, you need to ret result to main and store/print or pass an array  example out to output function to store the result in it and then print it in main.

Comment: the better way would be to store the result of each case in a local variable in menu and return that result to main and store the returned value in an array inside loop and print later.